# Error on Lattice Diamond: "core0 incorrect response (Write: 512 != Read:0) ... Problem cause is sample clock too slow or not continuous".

Tags: fpga, debugging, troubleshooting, lattice

Question for persons experienced on Lattice Diamond, I'm trying to test a previously developed project on Lattice Diamond. The project initially shouldn't have any problems because it was implemented and is running fine.

However, after opening the project in my own computer,  when I'm intending to run the reveal analyzer it gives me the following error message.

"Error: core0 incorrect response (Write: 512 != Read:0) See Reveal Troubleshooting Guide for more details. Problem cause is sample clock too slow or not continuous".

Anyone has any idea what's the problem about? and how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like the clock used by the integrated logic analyzer (Reveal) is not running / toggling. Do you have a free LED? Can you connect either a looked/stable signal from your clock modifying block or a toggling bit of a counter driven by the clock that is also used by Reveal?

Comment: 1. How fast is your sample clock? I use 133MHz from OSCH
2. Do you have any `default_nettype none or similar statements in your code. i have found they screw up reveal.